# About the "class" property/field

Tags: java

When you do:

```
MyClass.class.someMethod()
```

What exactly is the "class" field? I can't find it in the API docs. Is it an inherited static field?

I thought reserved keywords were not allowed as entity names.

Comment: Related post - [What does .class mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15078935/465053) & [How does a '.class' property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10076629/465053)

Comment: Another related post - [Java “.class” property - C# equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42228180/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read :

A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a `.' and the token class. The type of a class literal, C.Class, where C is the name of a class, interface or array type, is Class. If p is the name of a primitive type, let B be the type of an expression of type p after boxing conversion (§5.1.7). Then the type of p.class is Class. The type of void.class is Class.

[Java Language Specification: 15.8.2. Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

Comment: So the whole expression MyClass.class represents one single thing i.e. it's not a member access.

Answer (score 2):

`MyClass` is not the name of an object, it's a class name, so this is actually special syntax that retrieves the corresponding `Class<MyClass>` object for the named class. It is a language feature, not a real property of the `MyClass` class.

Comment: Class<|MyClass|> where |T| is the raw type of T, actually. If you had a variable `list` of type `List<String>`, `list.class` would return with a type of Class<List>.

Answer (score 2):

The `.class` is not actually a field.  You can think of is as more of an 'extension' like a file extension.  It is a token used to differentiate the Class Object as opposed to an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented here:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html