# How to reference a class declared in another file and add it as a static field

Tags: java

I have this:

```
package org.ores;
public class Asyncc {

    public static Class<Queue> Queue = new Class<Queue>();
}
```

but I get:

> 'Class(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class)' has private access
>   in 'java.lang.Class'

the Queue class looks like:

```
package org.ores;

public class Queue {

  public Queue(){

  }
}
```

it's in the same package but in a different file. My question is - is there a way to export the Queue class from the Asyncc class? Putting a ref to the Queue class as a static field on Asyncc?

Comment: `new Class<Queue>();` can't be right, although it isn't likely to lead to that error. What you want to do is `public static Class<Queue> Queue = Queue.class;`

Comment: @ernest_k yeah that looks right

Comment: Also, please follow naming conventions. The variable should be named `queue`, not `Queue`

Comment: @ernest_k it's a static var so uppercase is ok IMO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Of course!) The constructor `new Class()` is forbidden/private :)
, what you want is "just":

```
public static Class<Queue> queueClass = Queue.class;
```

see: [How does a '.class' property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10076629/592355) or [What does .class mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15078935/592355)

Comment: ...you "construct" the class by writing, compiling and loading it (to the class loader), from then on you cannot construct it, but refer to it'(s only instance) with the `.class` "keyword"/property.