# What is wrong with this switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

The following code returns an error, but I am not sure why. What needs to be changed to allow for compilation?

```
switch (DAO.class) {
    case BookDAO.class: 
        return bookDAO;
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) works with the `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int` primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (and `String` from Java 7 onwards). NOT `Class` types.

`DAO.class` returns Class object of `DAO`

Refer this for [what .class means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078935/what-does-class-mean-in-java)

Comment: @RiaD: I thought link will cover remaining things.

Comment: so then i have to use ifs ..great

Answer (score 4):

From Java Docs

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer

[More On this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 7 - you can use switch statements with Strings.
Then you could do something like this:

```
switch (DAO.class.getName()){
    case BookDAO.class.getName() : return bookDAO;
}
```

[getName():](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29)

Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definition of the switch statement:

Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths. **A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types**. It also works with **enumerated types** (discussed in Enum Types), **the String class**, and **a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer** (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

So **it is not allowed Class type** in the switch statement (Class classOfA = A.class;)