# Where does the class member come from?

Tags: java

Every Java class X can get its class name from `X.class`.

When I check it in the JDK documents, there isn't a member named `class` in `Object`.

Where does the `class` member come from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does .class mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078935/what-does-class-mean-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from Doea this answer your question?

Comment: @kedarsedai: that seems to be unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.class` is not a member of `Foo`, even though the syntax looks like it.

`Foo.class` is actually a [Class Literal expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

That means that it's just a special syntax in the language that's used to refer to the class of a given type.

If you used reflection to inspect `Foo` you wouldn't see a static field `class`.