# Java: int.class vs Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");

Tags: java, primitive

Is there a difference between `int.class` and `(Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");` in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What int.class mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271999/what-int-class-mean)

Comment: Standard `Class` doesn't have public `getPrimitiveClass` method. Consider adding library you are using.

Comment: I see it declared in Class.java as a native method.                                  `static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);`

Comment: Complementing @PratikKhadloya comment, to use `Class.getPrimitiveClass` method your class MUST be in the `java.lang` package. Not necessarily the JVM java/lang, it could be inside your project.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) doesn't have a `getPrimitiveClass(String)` method. Second, I found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/isPrimitivetypegetPrimitiveClassgetTypeDefaultValue.htm) link which implements a method with that name, from the link

> ```
> public static final Class<?> getPrimitiveClass(String typeName) {
>     if (typeName.equals("byte"))
>         return byte.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("short"))
>         return short.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("int"))
>         return int.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("long"))
>         return long.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("char"))
>         return char.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("float"))
>         return float.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("double"))
>         return double.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("boolean"))
>         return boolean.class;
>     if (typeName.equals("void"))
>         return void.class;
>     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not primitive type : " + typeName);
> }
> ```

So, if you're using the method above - the answer is no. They're the same.

Comment: I see it declared in Class.java as a native method.                                  `static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);`

Comment: Not public and not in the javadoc. You could maybe use reflection to call it. But it might well blow up in a different version of java.

Comment: `getPrimitiveClass` is declared in `java.lang.Class` as a native method which visibility is default.