# What's meant in Virtual Machine's Class object?

Tags: java

There is `getPrimitiveClass(String name)` method of `Class`. Its description is "Return the Virtual Machine's Class object for the named primitive type".

What does this mean? Can primitives can considered an object-like structures in JVM?

Comment: No, primitives are not objects, but sometimes you need a class to represent a primitive type (e.g. when using reflection).

Comment: That said, `java.lang.Class` does not have a `getPrimitiveClass(String name)` method. Which method are you asking about?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It actually does; it just has package visibility: https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l2312

Comment: @SolomonUcko Ah, thanks, I was just going by the API doc of [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: I've seen this method in field of Integer class:
public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");

Comment: It's undocumented, so there may not be a reliable description of what it does. One possible non-native implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25514941/21105992

Comment: Here's the relevant native code, if you're curious: https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/Class.c#l167, https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l717, https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.cpp#l207, https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/memory/universe.hpp#l286, https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/memory/universe.cpp#l439