# Creating an instance for Class?

Tags: java, class, object, instance

Looking at source code of Integer class, just stumble at this below line

```
Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");
```

And `getPrimitiveClass` is a native method.

```
 static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);
```

Why it became a native method ? really want to know.

How one can create an instance for `Class` ??  Does that differs with normal way of creating instance for ex : `Ex e = new Ex()` ?

Comment: You aren't creating an instance as far as I can tell. You're just obtaining a `Class` object.

Comment: Looks like this is a fashionable topic today, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983101/why-does-classinteger-c-int-class-compile).

Comment: @biziclop  I'm in a assumption that `obtaining a Class object = instance` ?

Comment: Well there's at least one instance, the `Class` object :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It is an instance of `Class` of course but not an instance of the type the class denotes. But you aren't creating anything, it just returns the value of `Integer.TYPE`, which is a compile type constant. I have no idea though why this method is native.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does int.class mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271999/what-does-int-class-mean)

Comment: @LBesancon That is a follow-up question for the answer. Not the exact question. Can you please verify again ?

Answer (score 2):

The comment above the method definition says:

```
/*
 * Return the Virtual Machine's Class object for the named
 * primitive type.
 */
 static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);
```

Since the (at least, Sun's) Virtual Machine is implemented in C, then I would assume that this is the reason for the method being `native`.