# Instantiate a class - java

Tags: java, class, enums

I have an enum class with the params id and Class.

```
ENUM1(1, class.class);

private int id;
private Class<?> clazz;

ENUM(int id, Class<?> clazz) {
    this.id = id;
    this.clazz = clazz;

}
```

The class implements an abstract interface. 
But how can i access the public methods of the "class.class"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just asked the same question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983540/creating-an-instance-for-class/31983719#31983719

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. As far as I'm aware, `class.class` isn't valid syntax, for example. What *exactly* are you trying to do, and what does this have to do with enums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following from the `Class` using reflection API.

```
Object obj = object.getClass().newInstance();//instantiates using default constructor provided that there are no checked exceptions thrown. Consider `Constructor` instead
object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("ImPublicMethodName", param1, param2).invoke(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering [Why is Class.newInstance() "evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil) I'd use something like:

```
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
    Object obj = ctor.newInstance();
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("yourMethod");
    method.invoke(obj);
```

The `getDeclaredXZY` methods optionally take the types of arguments as well.